# LayoutTransition animation working for appear and dissappear, but not for change flags

Tags: java, android, animation, android-cardview, layouttransition

I am using layout transition, to trigger some animations when i set views to View.GONE and View.VISIBLE.

it is working, there are 4 flags i am using to tell it what view to animate and when.
these are:

LayoutTransition.APPEARING-animate the view that is set to visible.
LayoutTransition.CHANGE_APPEARING-when view is set to visible, animate other views in group.
LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING-animate the view that is set to gone.
LayoutTransition.CHANGE_DISAPPEARING-when view is set to gone, animate other views in group.

this is the code where i set the animations

```
    transition.setAnimator(LayoutTransition.APPEARING, changeOut2);
    transition.setAnimator(LayoutTransition.CHANGE_APPEARING, changeOut2);
    transition.setAnimator(LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING, changeOut1);
    transition.setAnimator(LayoutTransition.CHANGE_DISAPPEARING, changeOut1);
```

my issue is that the change flags are not running the animations, but the others are working fine.

**EDIT: added listener**

Layout: There are three cardviews all in the same linear layout which has the LayoutTransition set to it. two are disappearing and the change_disappearing should run for the third cardview that remains in view.

i have added a listener as follows:

```
transition.addTransitionListener(new LayoutTransition.TransitionListener(){

        @Override
        public void startTransition(LayoutTransition transition, ViewGroup container, View view, int transitionType) {
            switch(transitionType){
                case LayoutTransition.APPEARING:
                    Log.i("anim", "APPEARING: "+view.toString());
                    break;
                case LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING:
                    Log.i("anim", "DISAPPEARING: "+view.toString());
                    break;
                case LayoutTransition.CHANGE_APPEARING:
                    Log.i("anim", "CHANGE_APPEARING: "+view.toString());
                    break;
                case LayoutTransition.CHANGE_DISAPPEARING:
                    Log.i("anim", "CHANGE_DISAPPEARING: "+view.toString());
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void endTransition(LayoutTransition transition, ViewGroup container, View view, int transitionType) {

        }
    });
```

I am getting correct logs for APPEARING and DISAPPEARING, but no logs from either of the CHANGE flags, although i did get change logs initially for the parent so i set the following:

```
        transition.setAnimateParentHierarchy(false);
```

logs currently look like:

```
11-20 16:04:05.195  13612-13612//*PACKAGE*/ I/anim﹕ APPEARING: android.support.v7.widget.CardView{4289d238 V.E...C. ......ID 0,0-1080,512 #7f080057 app:id/home_card}
11-20 16:04:05.195  13612-13612//*PACKAGE*/ I/anim﹕ APPEARING: android.support.v7.widget.CardView{428a3e80 V.E...C. ......ID 0,512-1080,1024 #7f080059 app:id/home_card1}
```

Comment: Maybe because the third view is not changing and has a fixed height and width ?

Comment: I will look through my old code. As i beleive i found the solution in the end.

Comment: @Michael -- did you ever find the solution for this, per your comment? I am having the exact same problem. My CHANGE_APPEARING and CHANGE_DISAPPEARING transition types actually *are* getting called, unless I set the animator for them, e.g.:

    layoutTransition.setAnimator(CHANGE_APPEARING, ...);

When I do that, the listeners no longer get called (and the animator doesn't run).